# List.Reverse() without any effect in C#

Tags: c#, list, reverse

Given the Following code:

```
List<Digit> tempDigits = input.Digits;
string test = tempDigits.ToString(); // -> {2,2,7}
tempDigits.Reverse();
string test2 = tempDigits.ToString(); // -> {2,2,7}
```

This is my code:
[image]
and that the result (in between, I renamed the variable according to naming convention  as suggested by Thiessen)

[image]

[image]

For some reason, the reverse soes not seem to do its job.

It must be something really simple. But I cant get what the Issue is. I hope, someone can help out.

Comment: Should probably start with a) using a different name for the new list and b) following C# naming conventions, which means variables should start with a lowercase letter. Doing both of those should remove any ambiguity about which list you're inspecting and/or reversing.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.reverse?view=netcore-3.1, reverse is void

Comment: @julianbechtold my bad, I thought you were using the one from Enumerable.

Comment: @Tieson renamed variables to tempDigits1.. did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the issue? It must be something simple, but looking at a few lines of code without knowing the context is a bit of a guessing game.

Comment: I’d like to see the code hidden behind the debugger window. I guess you might be reversing twice (what is Digits2)

Comment: Add code as text, and please also add where `this.Digits` is coming from (you could also show wha tis a `Digit`). Are `input.Digits` & `this.Digits` perhaps linked to the same list in the your code?

Comment: You need to show more of your code if you want your question answered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted would work correctly, in a vacuum. (Except, in what world does `List<>.ToString()` produce "`{2,2,7}`"?)

My main guess would be, as Lesiak commented, that `this.Digits` and `input.Digits` points to the exact same `List<>` instance. So `Digits1.Reverse()` reverses the list and `Digits2.Reverse()` reverses the reversal, putting it back how it started. Perhaps `this` and `input` are the same thing. Or perhaps they are two different things that happen to use the same underlying `Digits` list. Who knows?

There are many other possibilities, some of which would be impossible to guess at based on the information provided. For example:

- Maybe the `input` control that's giving you that list is trying to actively manage the list, and reorders it as soon as it notices it's been reversed.
- Maybe you're not using the `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` type, but instead you're referencing some other namespace where someone has written a `List<>` type that doesn't behave how you'd think it would. Maybe it doesn't even implement `Reverse()`, so the compiler is picking up on the `Enumerable.Reverse()` extension method, which does nothing to mutate the underlying data.

It really is impossible to know for sure without knowing more about your environment.

Answer (score 2):

The information you give is incomplete to address the issue.

A reproducible example from the information you provide does not show the same symptoms.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> digits = new List<int> {2,2,7};
        foreach(int digit in digits)
            Console.Write(digit);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        digits.Reverse();
        foreach(int digit in digits)
            Console.Write(digit);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Which gives the expected output

```
227
722
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hs9H0k

My guess would be, `this.Digits` is not a mutable reference. But that is just an hypothesis.

Comment: `List<>` is a mutable type. I don't think that's it.

Comment: `string.Join( ", ", digits )` would save you a couple of for loops here ;)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior both lists, in the case the OP shows, can be the same object. We need more information.

Comment: @Icepickle sure. Quick and dirty you know. At least you have no doubt what it does. But you can always edit it and get a few points.